# Replacing a class with another using Eclipse Transforms: can't fix ClassFormatError

Tags: java, osgi, eclipse-rcp, classloader, equinox

I'm using [Equinox Transforms](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Transforms) to replace one class with a custom version of it on the classpath. The transforms mechanism seems to be working properly, and I return an `InputStream` of the custom class from `public InputStream getInputStream(InputStream inputStream, URL transformerUrl)` of my transformer class.

But the loading of that class then results in a `ClassFormatError` with message `Truncated class file`. The only thing I can imagine causing this is a mismatch between Java versions, but I've done everything I know how to do to eliminate that as a source of the problem, to no avail.

I removed all but one JDK from Eclipse in the Installed JREs preference. I made sure all the plug-ins involved have the same Java version for their execution environment and the JRE on the build path is specified with the same execution environment. Target and product execution environments are defined the same also. I did a `clean all` in the workspace and re-launched eclipse and my runtime workbench many times, with `-clean`. After all this, I still get the error.

What else could it be if not Java versions causing this error? The [Equinox Transforms](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Transforms) page says it can be used to transform class resources. Has anyone actually done that?

Comment: latest commit on this project is 2013, it seems abandoned ..

Comment: Yeah I noticed that. But it was documented as working. Probably there's something I don't understand about loading of classes, because the equinox code seems to be doing what it's supposed to.

Comment: You should give a try to the "standard" way of overriding classes in osgi : weavinghook https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/core/org/osgi/framework/hooks/weaving/WeavingHook.html

Comment: Well that seems much easier, but I can;t get it to work either. I call setBytes on the wovenClass, and I see in the debugger that I'm getting the bytes from the modified class file. But the class doesn't exhibit any of the modified behavior. It acts as if the weaving didn't happen. I have a debug statement in the constructor and in one of the methods I've overridden, and I never see my debug output. Is there something else I'm supposed to to make the framework use the modified version of the class?

Comment: I noticed from the number of bytes loaded that I was actually getting the bytes of the original class and "replacing" the bytes in the original class with the same bytes. I fixed it by changing the way I defined the InputStream for the class. If you want to post an answer about using weaving, I'll accept it, and also give the details of the class loading problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a more standardized way to replace a class in osgi, through a `WeavingHook`. This hook should be registered as a service, and have the possibility to dynamically enhance a class.

See  [the WeavingHook Javadoc](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/core/org/osgi/framework/hooks/weaving/WeavingHook.html) or a concrete example with [Aries Proxy](https://github.com/apache/aries/blob/trunk/proxy/proxy-impl/src/main/java/org/apache/aries/proxy/impl/weaving/ProxyWeavingHook.java), which dynamically create proxies with the help of asm ([WovenProxyGenerator](https://github.com/apache/aries/blob/trunk/proxy/proxy-impl/src/main/java/org/apache/aries/proxy/impl/weaving/WovenProxyGenerator.java)).

Comment: Thanks, that was a much easier approach than creating my own transform using the generic hook extension. I ran into a problem initially because of the way I got the bytes of the replacement class. I originally tried in the plug-in that does the weaving: InputStream is = Activator.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/" + "qualified.class.name".replaceAll("\\.", "/") + ".class"); I thought it would resolve the replacement class in the current project, but it actually resolved the original class in the third party plug-in.

Comment: This worked: InputStream is = new URL("platform:/plugin/my.plugin.name/bin/path/to/replacement/class.").openConnection().getInputStream();